# Tag dispatch with template specialization

Tags: c++

Is it valid to dispatch a specialized tag? The following code can compile and run without any error. But I still want to confirm if it's valid to do so.

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct tag {};

// Specialize the tag
template <typename T>
struct tag<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type> {};

template <typename T>
T func(int i) {
    return real_func(tag<T>(), i);
}

string real_func(tag<string>, int i) {
    return to_string(i);
}

template <typename T>
T real_func(tag<T,  // <--------- Is this valid?
                typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>,
            int i) {
    return static_cast<T>(i);
}
```

Also, is there any other way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Maybe this example is a little contrived but why even use tag dispatch?  You could do the same thing here by specializing `real_func<std::string>` to use `to_string`  and all other `T`, or even us SFINAE to limit `T` for arithmetic types for the general case.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's some legacy code. So it seems a better way to achieve this is using SFINAE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specialized tag brings nothing useful. you use SFINAE a strange way, simply do:

```
template <typename T> struct tag{};

std::string real_func(tag<std::string>, int i) {
    return to_string(i);
}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
T real_func(tag<T>, int i) {
    return static_cast<T>(i);
}

template <typename T>
T func(int i) {
    return real_func(tag<T>(), i);
}
```